# chart web part reading excel file in document library

Tags: 2010, list-form, chart-web-part

I need to use **chart web part** in SP 2010 and I am having an excel file with few columns and end user uploads this excel **list** with updated values in the columns every week.

I need to generate a chart based on these values within the excel which is residing in the document library.

I am stuck with the approach, how to read the excel file and its columns that's consumed by chart web part in order to generate a **pie/line chart**. ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure Excel Services are enabled on your web application. Then you'll upload the Excel file to a document library. Then create a new page, and a web chart web part, and follow the steps in the web chart set up wizard. There a pretty decent walkthrough [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-Excel-content-in-an-Excel-Web-Access-Web-Part-25d58766-b3fb-41a4-9c86-3e50dc28a5ef). If you need more information, trying googling excel chart web part.

Comment: I have created and added the excel work book and added the excel web access web part.But my issue is how to display the chartw eb part based on this excel file?

Comment: I apologize. The link I sent your was for adding an excel web part, not a chart web part. To add a chart web part, click Add a Web Part then select Business Data >> Chart Web Part. Click "Data & Appearance, " "Connect Chart to Data," and "Connect to Excel Services." Enter the URL of your Excel file and the Table name of the data in your Excel file (the data has to be in a named range). Follow the steps to select the x and y axes. After those steps, you can click "Advanced Properties" to change height, width, color, chart type, etc.

Comment: This link might help: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/sharepoint/816/display-charts-sharepoint-2010-excel-services-webparts

Comment: Erin, Yes,I was going through the same link. also Corey Roth provided a  detailed explanation about Chart WebParts here :          http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/09/02/how-to-use-the-chart-web-part-with-excel-services.aspx

Comment: I have observed that, after I have created 5 columns and created a Chart web part and now I am having some other requirement and I have added a new column and this column would be added as X-Field in the chart.But, strangely, the newly added column is not visible for adding this as a X-Field  ,any idea why this is not displayed?

Comment: Did you change the range on the spreadsheet to include the new column?